# can't get value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

here is my ajax code

//html

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="name_id" />
```

//test.php

```
$.ajax(
    {
    url:"controller.php",
    data:$('#txtName').val(),
     success:
           function(result){
                   alert(result);
           }
    }
);
```

//controller.php

```
<?php 

echo $_POST['txtName'];
?>
```

it gives me an error

```
Undefined index:txtName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter name

```
$.ajax(
    {
    type:'POST',
    url:"controller.php",
    data:"param1="+$('#txtName').val(),
     success:
           function(result){
                   alert(result);
           }
    }
    );
```

and in PHP

read it by

```
$_POST['param1'];
```

---

**See**

- [Minified example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fi6mx1ikivsc7ne/ajax01.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `data:{txtName:$('#txtName').val()}`

```
$.ajax(
    {
    url:"controller.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{txtName:$('#txtName').val()},
     success:
           function(result){
                   alert(result);
           }
    }
    );
```

Comment: it gives the value on controller.php..i want it in the same page through alert

Comment: be more clear since it is AJAX request how can you go to controller.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$.ajax(
        {
        url:"controller.php",
        data:"txtName="+$('#name_id').val(),
        type: "POST",
         success:
               function(result){
                       alert(result);
               }
        }
        );
```

If you want to send entire form fields. You can use `data:$('#form_id').serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax(
{
url:"controller.php",
data:$('#txtName').val(),
 success:
       function(result){
               alert(result);
       }
}
);
```

When you are working with $("#... you have to use `<element id="txtName">`and not name="txtName". Change that and you are good to go :)